# CakePHP - Post type without dB table

Tags: cakephp

What's the best way of doing this in cakephp:

I have a Posts model+view+controller with a "Post type" field in my database - linking to my post type id.

The post type ids are:
- Preview
- Review
- News

What I'm asking is: What's the best way (natively) of retrieving  the post type name, without creating a table Post_types and linking it with a post_id.

I tried creating an array in the config lists, it worked but I think it can be better then this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `afterFind` method of your `Post` model and add there a `post_type` field to your results. See also the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1050/afterFind).

Comment: Thats perfect. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand your `post_type` is a enum field with values `preview, review, news` or a varchar in which you know only add these 3 types, right?

You could try the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(post_type) FROM posts;
```

This will return all `post_types` that are being used in your `posts` table.

In Cake you could do this either with the `find` or `query` method.

```
# Using find
$this->Post->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('DISTINCT(post_type)')
);

# Or using the query directly (maybe easier in this case)
$this->Post->query("SELECT DISTINCT(post_type) FROM posts;");
```

Answer (score -1):

associate your table posts with the table post_types with $hasOne. 
With a e.g. 
    $this->Post->find('all');
you would get the post and the post_type in one array.

Comment: Downvoted because the OP explicitly says that he doesn't want to use a table for the post types.